# My Macbook Pro keeps on restarting after installing OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos

My MacBook Pro keeps on restarting since I installed Mavericks. I can start it in Safe Mode, but it wouldn't start up at all normally - it throws me back to the username and password screen.

How can I stop this from happening and boot normally?

Comment: Did you reset PRAM and SMC?

Comment: yes i did but still it does the same thing